# CentOS is not showing log-in prompt after removing Gnome Desktop (does not switch to correct virtual terminal automatically)

Tags: centos

After installing CentOS 6.5 I removed Gnome Desktop Environment by running

```
yum groupremove Desktop
```

Now everything works fine, but whenever the computer starts there is no log-in prompt. The screen just shows CentOS progress bar. I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> in order to switch to terminal and see the log-in prompt.

How can I configure CentOS to do this automatically?

Comment: what's the content of the files `/etc/init/start-ttys.conf` and `/etc/init/start-ttys.override`?

Comment: There are lots of line breaks in this script, I can't paste it here using mini-Markdown

Comment: @pqnet This is the content of `/etc/init/start/ttys.con` I put a > sign at at beginning of each line instead of breaks  
>`start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]`  
>`env ACTIVE_CONSOLES=/dev/tty[1-6]`  
>`env X_TTY=/dev/tty1`  
>`task`  
>`script`  
>`. /etc/sysconfig/init`  
>`for tty in $(echo $ACTIVE_CONSOLES) ; do`  
>`[ "$RUNLEVEL" = "5" -a "$tty" = "$X_TTY" ] && continue`  
>`initctl start tty TTY=$tty`  
>`done`
>`end script`

Comment: Use backticks so the breaks will stay...

Comment: @Nima you can change your question and add in the information instead of using a comment.

Comment: @Jan backticks didn't work for comments

Comment: @pqnet I'll add it to main question, but first I should know this information is related to the problem

Comment: @Nima it is the upstart configuration file which is responsible for bringing up the terminals. In your case it looks like it is not the problem because it is unchanged from the original though. Having this information helped me guess that it could be just a problem with the loading screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the clean answer. Background - when installing the GUI by doing the
groupintstall remember that you had to set id:3:initdefault to id:5:initdefault in  /etc/inittab before typing init 6 for root to boot the GUI.

So just reset /etc/iniittab back to id:3:initedefault BEFORE! for doing
groupremove.

What appears to happen is the system has no way of finding the prompt because it's
still readying itself for a GUI install.

It take about 30 seconds to a minute to get the prompt back so be patient.

Comment: Great Answer!!! I know it's not much but it's short and sweet.  Welcome to U&L.SE

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that the login shell is there, but hidden by the progress bar screen.
The progress bar can be disabled by removing the `rhgb` option from the kernel command line.

You can try to edit temporarily the command line directly from grub at boot to test it. For a permanent change you have to edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and remove the word `rhgb` from the parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. After that you can regenerate the grub configuration file by using

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: There is no `/etc/default/grub/` file in my installation (CentOS 6.5). I manually edited `/etc/grub.conf` but there is no `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` parameter in this file and `rhgb` appears once in this line `kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=<UUID> rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet`. I removed `rhgb` and after reboot, instead of progress bar some information(about some services starting...etc) where shown, but still no login shell appeared

Comment: well, then I guess this is not the solution :( Sorry, I don't know more than this and I don't have a CentOS system where to test it. You probably have to wait for someone more experienced to come with a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Although not a good solution, but adding `chvt 2` (or any other valid virtual terminal number instead of 2) to `/etc/rc.local`
 seems to work as a temporary solution for me. This makes OS to switch to tty2 automatically.
I'm still looking for a better solution (showing a log-in shell on tty1 instead of CentOS progress bar)